# QoQ: LIKE comparison not returning all records expected

Tags: coldfusion, qoq

First time poster.  I can normally figure these things out on my own.  But alas I've hit a brick wall.

The basics here is I'm trying to hack in a product catalog into a custom CRM system that I have. I use a DAO system to pull data from the database with functions for read and filter.  The filter is a Query of Queries.

The issue currently is I'm building a search function for the page to search the items.

```
<cfset this.itemSet = this.damoney_itemsDAO.filter(this.searchData
       , "item_name LIKE '%#resultList#%'") />
```

When I dump the query here I get:

```
SELECT (fields) 
FROM   arguments.query(which is just a mass read) 
WHERE  item_name LIKE '%electrodes%'
```

In the DB we have items like "Blah Blah Electrodes" which aren't getting pulled. When I run it in the database I get the result I'm looking for.  But programatically it's only showing 2 items.

```
<cfoutput query="this.itemSet" startRow="#start#" maxRows="#perpage#">
```

Here is where I'm outputting the information and there are no if's or anything.  It's just HTML to list the items.

Happy to provide more information if needed.  But if anyone here has worked with a DAO system, and ran into this issue before, maybe you can provide some insight.

I also have a query option built into the DAO but I'm trying to avoid that at ALL costs due to the massive security issue involved with that.  (injections)

Comment: It would help to see a sample of the "expected" records AND the records "actually" returned. RE: *items like "Blah Blah Electrodes"* Silly question, but is the QoQ accounting for the fact that QoQ's are case sensitive? Because `'%electrodes%'` will not match "**E**lectrodes".

Comment: it does not.  But that gets me on the right path

Comment: *trying to avoid that ...due to the massive security issue involved with that* Exactly what risks are you talking about? Any queries in the app should be using `cfqueryparam` for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... WHERE lowercase(item_name) LIKE '%electrodes%'
```

LIKE is case-sensitive, so "Blah Blah Electrodes" and "Blah Blah electrodes" are all the way different.

Comment: Awsome,  Thank you,  I didn't not consider that at all.  That puts me on the right path.  I can't pass lowercase() to my DAO but i can add an exception to that.

That old saying, KISS.  ya.  i should remember that next time.

Comment: *"....LIKE is case-sensitive."* Not quite. As mentioned in the comments, ALL string comparisons in a QoQ are case sensitive, ie equal, IN, <>, etcetera. Also, lowercase not a supported function, but `lower()` is. See the  [QoQ Documentation:](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html)

Comment: My vote put your reputation into triple digits.  You owe me a beer.